# Need example of using fabricjs.d.ts with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, fabricjs

I use fabricjs in a project I'm attempting to convert to use TypeScript but I can't figure out how to use it. Previously I'd create my own custom objects by doing the following:

```
my.namespace.Control = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    id: "",
    type: 'Control',
    color: "#000000", 
    ...
});
```

In my new project, I've installed the TypeDefinition file from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabricjs/fabricjs.d.ts) but I can't figure out how I should use it?

Looking at the .d.ts file, fabric.Object doesn't appear to be a Function so isn't allowed to be passed to createClass, and createClass itself returns void, so I can't assign the value to a variable.

Even if all this worked, how should I format this so it works the TypeScript way? ie, what do I export so that I can import it elsewhere where the Control class is needed?

Anyone actually got any examples of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The old way of using your fabricjs.d.ts is at the top of your file :

```
/// <reference path="path/to/your/fabricjs.d.ts" />
```

If you get it with [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) you have to reference your tsd.d.ts bundle file

But now with typescript 1.6.2 and [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you only need to download the reference file via tsd to get the definitions in your code.

In the d.ts file you can found the 2 methods signature :

```
createClass(parent: Function, properties?: any): void;

createClass(properties?: any): void;
```

So your code seems invalid because fabric.Object as interface IObjectStatict cannot be asignable to type Function. You can cast fabric.Object as a Function doing

```
my.namespace.Control = fabric.util.createClass(<Function>fabric.Object, {
  id: '',
  type: 'Control',
  color: '#000000', 
  ...
});
```

Comment: I understand the answer above, however has there been any changes since? Also, I'm not sure about the format of the import declaration in my .ts file in order to use fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define a typescript class which extends a fabric class.

```
export interface IMindObjectOptions {
    item: IMindItem;
}

export interface IMindExpanderOptions  extends IMindObjectOptions {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    radius: number;
    isExpanded: boolean;
}

export class MindExpander extends fabric.Circle implements IMindObjectOptions {

    public constructor(options: IMindExpanderOptions) {
        const circleOptions: ICircleOptions = {
            originX: "center",
            originY: "center",
            left: options.x,
            top: options.y,
            radius: options.radius,
            stroke: "#000000",
            fill: options.isExpanded ? "#00FFFF": "#00FF00",
            selectable: false
        };
        super(circleOptions);
        this.item = options.item;
    }

    public readonly item: IMindItem;
}
```

---

!!! The above code works fine in browser, but not in nodejs enviornment.

---

To work in nodejs enviornment, such as run unit tests without a browser, you need:

```
import {assert} from "chai";
import * as f from 'fabric';
import {ITextOptions} from "fabric";

declare function require(s: string): any;
declare const __dirname: string;

const fabric = require("fabric").fabric;

interface ITextConstructor {
    new(text: string, options: ITextOptions): f.Text;
}
function getTextConstructor(): ITextConstructor {
    return fabric.Text;
}

describe("nodejs setup", function () {
    it("fabric is imported correctly", function () {
        const x = fabric.Text as f.Text;
        assert.equal(typeof x, "function");
    });
    it("fabric class is extensible", function () {
        class SubText extends getTextConstructor() {
            public constructor(text: string, options: fabric.ITextOptions) {
                super(text, options);
            }
        }

        const c = new SubText("Hello", {left: 100, top: 100});
        assert.equal(c.text, "Hello");
        assert.isNotNull(c);
    });
});
```